# Recalculating values from a complicated function

Tags: python, data-transformation

I have two pairs of x and y coordinates that I want to plot on two separate graphs. The range of `x` is the same for both graphs; starting from `0` to `1`. However, they have different values for pretty much the whole length of the data set. This means that they take different steps to get to `1`. For example, let me show you some example slices of the data (with headers for clarity):

```
my_data[0]
my_data[1]

>>['x1','y1','x2','y2']
>>[0, 0, 0, 70]

my_data[0]
my_data[30]

>>['x1','y1','x2','y2']
>>[.03, .82, .23, 7]
```

As you can see, `x1` and `x2` have different values at index:30. This creates a big problem for the visualization software that I use. I need `x1` and `x2` to increase at the same rate. So I think what I want to do is scrap all the `x2` values and replace them with `x1`. Then somehow I need to look up the corresponding `y2` value in order to preserve the data. The data is not a simple function that I can easily solve for y, like the textbook `y=x^2`. It has a complicated shape, here is the line plot:

[image]

**Question:** If I reformat my `x2` what is the best way to calculate the correct `y2` for each index? Ideally python is what I'm looking for, but feel free to articulate in terms of concepts.